# How to model collection of mixed entities using EF code first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 in VS2010. 
I have a working sample with two types: Person, Business
I'd like to add a collection like

```
DbSet<Customer> Customers
```

where the objects in Customers can be either a Person or Business. In my app I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
mycontext.Customers.Add(new Person());
mycontext.Customers.Add(new Business());
```

I think the Customer table could look like

```
id (id of Person or Business)
discriminator
```

How can this be achieved with code first?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Base-Class **Customers** with an ID Property and derive **Person** and **Business** from *Customers*?

Comment: Or interface depending on if Person and Business share logic

Comment: I totally agree. But yet not apperent from OP's Question.

Comment: The person and Business classes are already implemented as completely separate, and in different tables. The only thing common about them is that either can be a customer.

Comment: Thats totally ok and its not important... You just create a new Class now. This new Class you call `Customer`. In that new Class you create a Property with the name: `Id`. After done that you can derive Person and Business from Customer, like that: `public class Person : Customer { }` Now you can use Customer for both of them: `mycontext.Customers.Add(new Person());` and  
`mycontext.Customers.Add(new Business());`

Comment: That will just put Person and Business in a single table. Person and Business are already in their own tables. I need Customer to be in a separate table.